# How do I force wget to save directory files as index.html?

Tags: wget

When recursive wget encounters a URL like http://example.com/directory that redirects to http://example.com/directory/ it saves the file as `example.com/directory` based on the pre-redirect URL. If it would have been asked to download the URL with the trailing slash, it would save it to `example.com/directory/index.html`.

Then when it later encounters `http://example.com/directory/file.html` it deletes `example.com/directory` in order to make it a directory instead.

How do I get http://example.com/directory to be saved as `example.com/directory/index.html`? Note that wget sees it redirect to a path with a trailing slash so it *should* already know this!